# Finite element convergence rate and possion's ratio

Tags: finite-element, convergence, poisson

I am running simulations of a cantilever beam where it is fixed on one end and negative force applied to the other end. The first simulation is with 4-node linear quadrilateral elements and the other is simulation with 9-node quadratic quadrilaterial elements. At first I ran the simulations with a poisson's ratio of 0.3, then with a Poisson's ratio of 0.499 and calculated the convergence rate.

I got the convergence rate for the 4-node as 1.7 but it should be 2 and for the 9-node it is 3. My question is why they are different than each other is it because 4-node is linear and 9-node is quadratic.

In addition, what would be the reasons that cause the convergence rate to be 1.7 not 2? when I asked my professor he said your algorithm is right but you need to know why its not 2.
 When I changed the Poisson's ratio to 0.499. everything messed up it the 4node simulation but it in it is fine for the 9node, why is that? why the 9-node can handle 0.499 material and 4-node can'

Comment: Regarding the poisson's ratio and the element type: quadratic elements will always perform better than linear elements when you have a high poisson's ratio. Quadratic simpy have 'more options to move' and thus to satisfy the constraint of nearby incompressibility.

Comment: Maybe you could add graphs/plots or tell us how you calculated your convergence rate. What's the difference between your numerical and the analytical solution?

Comment: I know the 9node perform better with higher poisson's ratio but why its better/

Comment: I will add a plot of the error and convergence rate of the 4node problem to show you , the answer should be 2 but I got 1.7 for some reason.

Comment: how can I add a plot here?

Comment: Search for 'volumetric locking' in the available literature.

Comment: I looked into it but still I think it did not answer my question, how can upload a plot here ? @P.G.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

[image]

here some plot of the deformation and how it converge to the exact solution as the size of mesh increase, the last plot shows the convergence rate of the solution. I am not sure why it is 1.7 but in theory it should be 2 for some reason of how the material behavior to the 4node could you help me out with this

Comment: This should be added to the original question and not as an answer.